# Decryption is throwing System.SecurityException error in apex class

Tags: apex, cookies, decrypt

I'm creating community site and storing the password in cookies in the form of encryption. Now I've to decrypt that password. but decryption is not working. getting below error.

> System.SecurityException: Given final block not properly padded Class.System.Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV: line 60, column 1

Apex class code:

```
public PageReference directlogin(){ 
    Cookie getPasswd = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('password');
    String decryptedPassword= null;
    if(getPasswd !=null){
        Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
        Blob datac = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(getPasswd.getValue());
        try{
            Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, datac); // here error throwing
            decryptedPassword = decryptedData.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            ex=e; 
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're generating a *random* key *every* time the method is called. In order for the decryption to be successful, you need to use the *same* key instead. You should store this key either in a custom setting or elsewhere. Do not store the key in a cookie, since it would be visible to the user.

Comment: you are really great to capture the error. Appreciate you. Thank you.